# Convert HTML to RTF (Rich Text) using a web-browser control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, copy-paste, rtf

```
var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.CreateControl(); // only if needed
webBrowser.DocumentText = *yourhtmlstring*;
while (_webBrowser.DocumentText != *yourhtmlstring*)
    Application.DoEvents();
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
*yourRichTextControl*.Paste();
```

The above code works fine on a local computer, but when I deploy it on a remote computer or on shared hosting webserver, the copy command doesn't work at all. I checked and found that Clipboard is always empty, so RFT text is always empty. It seems the web-browser control `SelectAll` and `Copy` commands don't work on deployment servers. I am looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar problems with the web browser control. I think it was related to the settings of Internet Explorer. Try reducing the security settings in Internet Explorer.